# monero-wallet-gui v0.14.1.0 will not fully sync on local node

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

I'm running Monero GUI v0.14.1.0 , and on the local node will not fully sync,if if left all night, its stays around 115 blocks remaining,and actually blocks increase slightly.
When i switch to remote node , node.moneroworld.com port 18089, it will sync fully, and when i switch back to local node it will not sync.
Looks like i could only send a transaction on a remote node.
Any help thanks.

Comment: @gary - Can you check whether it is actually stuck on a certain block? You can get a status overview by typing `status` into the command box on the `Settings` page.

Comment: 1912592/1913611   v11, is the current height, but the daemon blocks remaining is 115, or 116 stuck on that. I think since i upgraded to the new version of linux mint 19.2 tina, from 19.1 , alot of problems came up, like openbazaar does not work properly, vpn, monero gui, shutdown, networks, so i think i will have to delete linux mint and  everything else and use a different linux distro on my laptop and start fresh all over. And now currently stuck on 115 blocks.